# Should I be using sprites for jQuery Sliders?

Tags: jquery, html, css, performance, css-sprites

I understand that using sprites saves HTTP requests and therefore makes a page load faster.

How does that relate to jQuery sliders?  Does a jQuery slider load all images on page load or load them as needed? Is it possible/recommended to use sprites for jQuery sliders?

If anyone is wondering, the slider I am using is:  https://github.com/maelstrom/SecretSource

The basic HTML:

```
             <div id="banner-fade" class="responsive-container img-polaroid">
                <ul class="slideshow">
                  <li><img src="img/slider/image1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                  <li><img src="img/slider/image2.jpg" alt=""></li>
                  <li><img src="img/slider/image3.jpg" alt=""></li>
                </ul>
             </div>
```

Comment: for me i'm not quite sure that help because it make your images load slower in first visit and make your visitor go away in your site, just simple customize the size of your images to load faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with jQuery Sliders, all images in your HTML are going to to be fetched. Therefore, if you use sprites, you'll make a single request for the three images instead of three separate requests. Is it possible? Yes. Recommended? Probably, do you want to minimize HTTP requests and make your HTML slightly harder because you have to now position the image?

Be sure to remember that by making a sprite, you can't download the separate images in parallel.

In the end, no one can tell you always do it one way, you need to weight the pros and cons. In  this case, I would put the three images into a sprite to save a network connection, but someone else may prefer the benefit of parallel downloads.

Comment: If your goal is to have a fast website that serves a great user experience, would you put all images into one, large image and position everything you need, or is that a bad idea for reasons I don't yet understand?

Comment: Trying to maintain all your images into a single sprite can be a maintenance nightmare. You also don't want to force the user to load all images upfront (in the form of a global image sprite). You have to strike a balance, put images that go together in a sprite. You don't want a single request, but you don't want too many either.

Comment: Great, I appreciate your help. I didn't realize that more than one element can be downloaded at the same time in parallel.  That seems like it would be faster than a global sprite, and much easier.

Comment: It would, but if you're making requests for 50 images when you start the page, it could start hurting you because there's a limit on the amount of parallel requests.

Comment: I believe I will have 3 or 4 image requests at the max for the page I am working on.  I already have some sprites for smaller images and buttons, and I have two sliders.  I will (attempt to) create a sprite for each slider like you suggested.

Comment: Juan are you going to meetup tonight?